# JWT Authentication -Token Validation Fails

Tags: wordpress, flutter, rest, woocommerce

When i try to validate my Bearer Token i get this Error :

{ "code": "jwt_auth_no_auth_header", "message": "Authorization header not found.", "data": { "status": 403 } }

I tried all the possible solutions but without any result , if someone can help me to solve this i will appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: Did you pass a header when requesting data? thru API?

Comment: Share your POST method code for better understanding of your problem

Comment: Im trying to validate it like this  =>> https://fitme.guelizarrondissement.ma/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate and i pasted the token i got into the bearer token but its not validated